# What is the difference between MPI_Type_struct and MPI_Type_create_struct in MPI?

Tags: c++, c, types, mpi, hpc

I have seen both of the two commands being used for the creation of Datatypes for sending and receiving messages in MPI.

As far as I understand the take the same input arguments and they
return a new datatype given an older one.

So what is the difference and when should I use the one instead of the other?

Answer (score 0):

Documentation says that the first one is deprecated and MPI_Type_create_struct should be used instead. Both do exactly same thing.

Source:
https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v4.0/man3/MPI_Type_struct.3.php
https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v4.0/man3/MPI_Type_create_struct.3.php

Comment: `MPI_Type_struct()` has been deprecated since MPI 2.0, and __removed__ from the standard since MPI 3.0. FWIW, Open MPI 4 does not include its prototype in `mpi.h` by default, so you definitely have to modernize your code and use `MPI_Type_create_struct()` instead.